# Наложение объектов с видео на изображение

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Нахожу координаты бинаризованных движущихся объектов на видео (обычное traffic video) и значения пикселей этих объектов с оригинальных фреймов. Далее сохраняю все это дело в бинарь в виде массива массивов, и затем нужно накладывать эти объекты на картинку заднего фона видео, которая уже сохранена. В чем заключается наложение? Нужно прогонять по массиву изображения массивы со значениями пикселей объектов по координатам из массива координат? Или есть что-то другое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исхожу из того, что фрейм видео и картинка заднего плана одинакового размера, в противном случае нужно привести к одинаковому или пересчитать координаты пикселей. 
Ниже код, где frame - BGR изображение из кадра видео, bgr - BGR фоновая картинка, mask - GRAYSCALE бинарная маска, полученная вами выше:

```
 mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) # выравниваем каналы под BGR
 tmpim1 = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,mask) # вырезаем интересующий фрагмент из кадра
 tmpim2 = cv2.bitwise_and(bgr,cv2.bitwise_not(mask)) # вырезаем всё кроме фрагмента в фоновой картине (картинке затемняем)
 outim = cv2.bitwise_or(tmpim1,tmpim2) # складываем картинки, получаем искомое изображение
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не подскажете мне еще один момент.. возможно-ли с помощью opecvшных функций накладывать объекты с видео на картинку таким образом, чтобы они появлялись в одно время? Или тут никак не обойтись без numpy функций..

Comment: @EA008 а что значит в одно время, и чем плох numpy?

Comment: допустим у меня есть видео 10 мин, мне необходимо сжать его, например до 1 минуты, чтобы объекты появлялись по много штук в кадре, сегментированные и промазанные через альфа канал. Я пошел путем, который описал в вопросе, сохранил каждый объект в отдельный массив и эти массивы запихал в один большой массив Значения, то же сделал с координатами и запихал их в массив Координаты. И так понимаю нужно в картинку(массив) загонять массив значений по массиву координат?

Comment: вероятно мы принимали разные напитки, потому что я все слова отлично понимаю, а то что из них составлено - просто никак, ни одно предложение, честное слово ))

Comment: :D сорян. Попробую еще раз.
Координаты бинаризованных объектов записываются в массив [[0,218],[0,219]].. для каждого кадра один массив, для всего видео много таких массивов которые я записываю в один массив. Нахожу BGR значения пикселей объектов по координатам с оригинальных фреймов и записываю их в массив, и снова для каждого кадра свой массив.

Comment: Вероятно я пошел не правильным путем

Comment: Наворотили гору массивов непонятно зачем... Бинарные маски разных объектов одного кадра можно просто объединить bitwise_or, зачем их по отдельности в массив? А дальше все то же самое, для каждого кадра, можно кадры отфильтровать ещё скажем если найдено то что интересно

Comment: Не догоняю, объединить бинарные маски разных объектов,чтобы они выглядели как один объект?

Comment: Если вам нужно чтобы объекты имели какую-то интерактивность, например чтобы можно было кликать по каждому отдельно - тогда объединять нельзя, я в общем не понимаю что вы пытаетесь сделать в итоге поэтому наверно говорим о разном

Comment: Пытаюсь наложить по много объектов на картинку за кадр (фото прикрепил к вопросу)

Comment: Ну ок, а в видео что, что эти цифры означают?

Comment: время появления объекта я думаю

Comment: может брать маски белых пикселей, по ним брать значение с фреймов, сохранять полученные маски и потом их накладывать на картинку по несколько масок за раз?